# Cycle detect, XmlTransient and unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb

I have two class:

Restaurant

```
public class Restaurant implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "restaurant", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<Comment> comments;
}
```

Comment

```
public class Comment implements BasicVO, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    @XmlTransient
    public Restaurant getRestaurant() {
        return restaurant;
    }
}
```

I used annotation @XmlTransient to prevent "Marshalling Error: A cycle is detected in the object graph.", but how can I retrieve back information about restaurant field in comment class? When I try to pass Comment object by WebService information about restaurant is of course lost (because of XmlTransient). How can I get this information back?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question correctly, you can just find comment by id.

For example 
`Restaurant restaurant = entityManager.getReference(Comment.class, id).getRestaraunt();`

Of course it requires some logic on your server side.